# Insert bytes at front in NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c, insert, nsdata, nsmutabledata

How can I insert a byte at the beginning of my `NSMutableData`? I understand that there is a `replaceBytesInRange:` method but that will just replace the bytes. There is a bunch of `insertXAtIndex:` methods but none are for bytes. How can I do this? One way I can think of doing this is:

```
NSMutableData *theData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:myByte];
[theData appendData:myOriginalData];
myOriginalData = nil;
```

But there must be a better way.

I also tried this but it didn't work:

```
char *sec = "Second!";
char *fir = "First!";

NSMutableData *theData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:(const void *)sec length:7];
[theData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0) withBytes:(const void *)fir];

NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", str1); //Prints "Second!"
```

Comment: I haven't tried but what about using `replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:` but specify a zero-length range?

Comment: @rmaddy I tried that but it didn't work either. See my edit to make sure I know what you meant.

Comment: I guess that won't work. It must look at the range length to know how many bytes to get from the 'withBytes:` parameter.

Comment: @rmaddy After testing it, yes it does.

Comment: @rmaddy you were right on your theory that a zero length range would do it. The trick was that you can specify the length of the bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[theData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0) withBytes:(const void *)fir length:strlen(fir)];
```

ought to do the trick.

Comment: Nope. Just replaces Second! with First!.

Comment: Ah, had the wrong string in strlen. Now it prints "First!Second!" for me.